# MySQL - RANDOMLY choose a row in a 14Millions rows table - testing does not make sense

Tags: mysql

I have been looking on the web on how to select a random row on big tables, I have found various results, but then I analyzed my data and figured out that the best way for me to go is to count the rows and select a random one of those with `LIMIT`

While testing I start to wonder why this works:

```
 SET @t = CEIL(RAND()*(SELECT MAX(id) FROM logo));
 SELECT id
 FROM logo
 WHERE
     current_status_id=29 AND
     logo_type_id=4 AND
     active='y' AND
     id>=@t
 ORDER BY id
 LIMIT 1;
```

and gives random results, but this always returns the same 4 or 5 results ?

```
SELECT id
FROM logo
WHERE
    current_status_id=29 AND
    logo_type_id=4 AND
    active='y' AND
    id>=CEIL(RAND()*(SELECT MAX(id) FROM logo))
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1;
```

the table has MANY fields (almost 100) and quite a few indexes. over 14 Million records and counting.  When I select a random it is almost NEVER that I have to select it from the table, I always have to select depending on various fields values (all indexed).

Could it be a bug of my MySQL server version (`5.6.13-log Source distribution`)?

Comment: Works on my machine. Are you sure you're running the correct queries and against the same data?

Comment: Yes, even optimized the table just in case (took forever) and still have the same problem.  if I change the parameters in the WHERE I get different results, but they are always 4 or 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is that this statement in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand):

> > RAND() in a WHERE clause is re-evaluated every time the WHERE is executed.

is simply not always true.  It is true when you do:

```
where rand() < 0.01
```

to get an approximate 1% sample of the rows.  Perhaps the MySQL optimizer says something like "Oh, I'll evaluate the subquery to get one value back.  And, just to be more efficient, I'll multiply that row by `rand()` before defining the constant."

If I had to guess, that would be the case.

Another possibility is that the data is arranged so the values you are looking for has one row with a large id.  Or, it could be that there are lots of rows with small ids at the very beginning, and then a very large gap.

Your method of getting a random row, by the way is not guaranteed to return a result when you are doing filtering.  I don't know if that is important to you.

EDIT:

Check to see if this version works as you expect:

```
SELECT id
FROM logo cross join
     (SELECT MAX(id) as maxid FROM logo) c
WHERE current_status_id = 29 AND
      logo_type_id = 4 AND
      active = 'y' AND
      id >= RAND() * maxid
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1;
```

If so, the problem is that the max id is being calculated and then there is an extra step of multiplying it by `rand()` as execution of the query begins.

Comment: That would be OK with me.  I only need one at the time so even if it executes once every time I run the query, I will always get a different `RAND()` value.  It seems like that in the WHERE clause the RAND() doesn't return random values correctly.  Could it be a bug of my version:  `5.6.13-log` ?

Comment: After your update, every refresh returns the following IDs 11030959, 11071792, and 11042523, with 11030959 returning over and over and over and the other two once in awhile.  Keep in mind that I have lots of holes in the maxid is currently 14597061 and while testing changed from 14597059.  The increase did not change the results

Comment: @Fabrizio . . . So your issue is probably the distribution of the values, rather than an incorrect execution of `rand()`.  If you want, ask another question about the best way to get a random value.  Your current method is not working.

Comment: That is what I was thinking too, but `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM logo
WHERE current_status_id = 29 AND logo_type_id = 4 AND active = 'y'` returns 32,184, surely a lot more than just 3, and the distribution is constant all over the table (I.E. not all at the beginning or end)

Comment: OK, I answered my own question thanks to your suggestion.  32k out of a 14M rows, the `RAND()*14M` it is very likely to find a hole. I am going to get a COUNT(*) followed by a `LIMIT (PHP)rand(0,countid), 1`.